# Hide or remove Action Bar on specific Activity | Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar

How I can remove Action Bar on specific activity not for all application, for example I have Sign Up activity and for this activity I want to remove Action Bar

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#hide()

Answer (score 65):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** use NoActionBar theme for your Activity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".SignUpActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

and in your **styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It fits within the developer accepted guidelines @Yessine Mahdouani

Answer (score 26):

from within your activity:

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

I would suggest to migrate to ToolBar, new Android API for the same purpose. The main benefit of ToolBar is that you can treat it like other views, it guarantees to you a more flexible approach.

Comment: Why load the action bar in the activity at all, then hide it? Seems like a waste to me. Just don't include it in the layout to start with.

Comment: Because if you uses a generic root layout you could have choosen to have the ActionBar everywhere to reuse the same code.

Answer (score 4):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This will definitely remove the ActionBar in all Activities and that is not what he wants

Answer (score 3):

If you have an ActionBar, you can use `getActionBar().hide();`
If you have a SupportActionBar, you can use `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Remove Action Bar on specific Activity go to Activity java file here your Activity class extends with **AppCompatActivity** remove the AppCompatActivity and extends with **Activity** and go to xml file and select Theme **NoTitleBar** or go to Manifests file select your Activity and add Theme on your Activity **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>**

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin you can use `supportActionBar?.hide()`